# Как в yii2 поменять заголовок письма отправляемого клиенту?

Tags: php, yii2

Расскажите, как поменять заголовок в письме, приходящем на почту клиенту?

Comment: Сформируй новый заголовок и передай в mailer. Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе код, которым вы отправляете письмо. Иначе -- только тыкать пальцем в небо и гадать, что у вас там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вы имели в виду **тему письма**. Если так, то тему письма можно передать в методе **setSubject()**

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contact/html')
     ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
     ->setTo($form->email)
     ->setSubject($form->subject)
     ->send();
```